# Why does this common JavaScript method to deeply flatten arrays not work universally?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I run into this interesting code challenge: "Create a function that takes an array and returns the sum of all items in the array."

My solution is:

```
function sumArray(arr) {
    var merged = [].concat.apply([], arr);
    var sum = 0;
    merged.forEach(function(item) {
        sum = sum + item;
    });
    return sum;
}
```

The problem is that the above solution fails for: `sumArray([1, [2, [1]], 3]), 7` because the flattening method does not go deep enough. Concretely, in the above case, `console.log(merged)` is `[1, 2, [1], 3]`;

What flattening method would go as deep as necessary?

Comment: take `array.flat(Infinity)`. see [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: The simplest techniques for this would definitely be recursive, perhaps something like `const sumArray = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((t, n) => t + (Array.isArray(n) ? sumArray(n) : n), 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array#flat() with infinite depth , or actual depth if known.

```js
function sumArray(arr) {  
   return arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
}

console.log(sumArray([1, [2, [1]], 3]))
```